# Running python unit test over LSF

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, unittest2

I need to parallelize my python unit-tests which I wrote using the default unittest module.
I'm trying to decide between two approaches:

1. keep using **unittest** but use a custom 'multiprocess' runner which can spawn a test using [Platform LSF](http://www.platform.com/workload-management/high-performance-computing) (remote execution tool) an example can be found in the [TestOOB](http://testoob.sourceforge.net/features.html) project.
2. Use **py.test** and customize the pytest-xdist plugin to run LSF instead of SSH.

I lean towards #1 since I already have a working setup and particularly the test suite generation (which is using a generator that parse an excel spreadsheet and is not trivial)

Any recommendation on a particular approach to follow ?

*Note:* my company is using LSF and I must use it for resource sharing with other teams.

Answer (score 1):

i'd first try to simply install "pytest-xdist" from pypi and run your existing tests with "py.test -n 5" in 5 parallel processes. If that basically works it means that modifying pytest-xdist to use the LSF transport is a worthwhile option.  Effectively you will need to look into extending execnet (http://codespeak.net/execnet) which is the underlying library for distributing execution. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Since it's been a while I already implemented it. I follow a similar approach as you are saying, distributing locally before plugging LSF into the mix. I ended up going for option 1. I switched my test framework from regular unittest module to the TestOOB framework. I then wrote a customized 'runner' to run tests over LSF. I pass the test data across machines using Pyro objects.